# What wont this simple functional component example work?

Tags: reactjs, components

I have this React child component....

```
const MainLink = ({linkText}) => {

  return (
    <h1>{linkText}</h1>
  )
}
export default MainLink
```

I have this Parent component that calls the child component...

```
import MainLink from "./MainLink"
const MainLinks = () => {

    return (
        <>
        <MainLink key='1' linkText={"Home"}/>
        <MainLink key='2' linkText="Home"/>
        </>
    )
  }
  export default MainLinks
```

I can't seem to pass any value for "linkText" to the child component. It always comes up

`{linkText: undefined}`

and the output is

I thought one of these would work. What am I missing here?

Comment: I just test your code it work, which version react you use, did you start with a fresh react app ?

Comment: It's like version 18. My computer is doing weird things. I think I am having some weird memory problems. I had two other bizzarro errors after this one. Thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: In conclusion this should work. I was experiencing issues with webpack which made it seem as if this didn't work- it was not recompiling my code on every save. Have to figure that out, sorry for wasting everyone's time.